# Eliminar key en array en PHP

Tags: php, array

Estimados estoy intentando contruir un array no multidimencional, pero me esta dando como resultado esto: Aca es donde construyo el arrar

```
 if($values["field_value"]==null){

                        $arrayValue[]=array($values["field_name"]=>$values["value"]);

                    }else{

                        $arrayValue[]=array($values["field_name"]=>$values["field_value"]);
                    }
```

Y como resultado:

```
[0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["CUIT"]=>
    string(11) "20-333333-6"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Telefono movil"]=>
    string(10) "333333"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Condicion ante IVA"]=>
    string(21) "Responsable Inscripto"
  }
```

Pero en el llamado no quiero depender de la key [0][1]etc, quiero llamar al array por su nombre ["Condicion ante IVA"], es decir no quiero depender de llamar al array asi [2]["Condicion ante IVA"].
Como puedo hacer para lograr esto?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando pones

```
$arrayValue[]=array($values["field_name"]=>$values["value"]);
```

le estás diciendo explícitamente a PHP que construya un array bidimensional

Para que sea asociativo unidimensional, pues reemplaza esa línea por esto:

```
$arrayValue[$values["field_name"]] = $values["value"];
```

Aplica lo mismo en el `else`, pero con el valor correspondiente.

Comment: El problema esta al acceder al Array, primero me muestra `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion` ahi es cuando utilizo `json_decode()`, luego cuando coloco `$values["id"]` me muestra `PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'id'`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un array multidimensional como este:

```
$arr = [
    ["CUIT" => "20-333333-6"],
    ["Telefono movil" => "333333"],
    ["Condicion ante IVA" => "Responsable Inscripto"],
];
```

y quieres tener este otro asociativo:

```
$expected = [
    "CUIT" => "20-333333-6",
    "Telefono movil" => "333333",
    "Condicion ante IVA" => "Responsable Inscripto",
];
```

#### Solucion

Puedes recorrer el array multidimensional original *mergeando* cada uno de los arrays asociativos con otro vacío creado previamente.

```
<?php
$arr = [
    ["CUIT" => "20-333333-6"],
    ["Telefono movil" => "333333"],
    ["Condicion ante IVA" => "Responsable Inscripto"],
];
$expected = [
    "CUIT" => "20-333333-6",
    "Telefono movil" => "333333",
    "Condicion ante IVA" => "Responsable Inscripto",
];

$result = [];
foreach($arr as $internal_array) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $internal_array);
}
var_dump($result === $expected); // true
```

Comment: El problema esta al acceder al Array, primero me muestra `PHP Notice: Array to string conversion` ahi es cuando utilizo `json_decode()`, luego cuando coloco `$values["id"]` me muestra `PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'`

Comment: Puedes decirnos en que línea te da ese error? Inicialmente las respuestas de los compañeros son correctas, y en el código que has publicado no utilizas json_decode. ..